# Iterating through complex json array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm recieving the following multidimensional array via an ajax post:

```
array(1) {
["result"] => array(3) {
    [0] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(1)
        "0" [1] => array(2) {
            ["id"] => string(5)
            "1§10" ["children"] => array(2) {
                [0] => array(1) {
                    ["id"] => string(6)
                    "1§3$0"
                } [1] => array(1) {
                    ["id"] => string(6)
                    "1§1$0"
                }
            }
        }
    } [1] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(1)
        "1" [1] => array(1) {
            ["id"] => string(5)
            "3§20"
        }
    } [2] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(1)
        "2" [1] => array(2) {
            ["id"] => string(5)
            "2§30" ["children"] => array(1) {
                [0] => array(1) {
                    ["id"] => string(6)
                    "2§2$0"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Is there a way to return only the strings one by one with php? The depth of the of the string in the array does not matter what so ever since i will only parse and explode the id strings.

Comment: try `array_walk_recursive()` for more information have look https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php, remember there is some limitation with this function , make sure go through  with that.

Comment: you can also use ```$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array), RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY); foreach ($it as $item) {...}```

Comment: @Stantastic Did my post answered you? this question is still in the unanswered queue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement simple recorsice function as:

```
function printString($arg) {
    if (is_string($arg))
        echo $arg . PHP_EOL;
    else (is_array($arg)) {
        foreach($arg as $e)
            printString($e);
    }
}
```

Or use `array_walk_recursive` as:

```
function printStr($item, $key) {
    echo $item . PHP_EOL;
}

array_walk_recursive($arr, 'printStr');
```

If you **only need the "id" string** do:

```
function printId($item, $key) { if ($key == "id") echo $item . PHP_EOL; }
array_walk_recursive($arr, 'printId');
```

Reference: [is_string](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php), [is_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php), [array-walk-recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)